# create multiple Rectangle/Boxed in HTML

Tags: html

I want to make an html page contains multiple rectangle /boxes (with text) in hierarchy format. I tried to search a sample from the net but not successful. I I'm using visual studio 2012. by the way, I'm newbie in html. thank you in advance. below is a sample format.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIoFZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You won't be able to do this with just HTML. HTML describes the document layout, you will need CSS to complete your styling requirements. Use an html structure to define the relationship between elements then style them. Investigate the various HTML lists

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty example to get you going. It's fairly limited but you haven't given us much to work with https://jsfiddle.net/n5zhdg8s/

Comment: Thank you Jon P for this sample HTML as my startup reference.

Comment: I will inject this HTML to spotfire.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is good for grid. but if you use enterprise application don't use bootstrap because it loaded unwanted classes(all classes will be loaded while page rendering).

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
 </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in taking a look at a stylesheet library that handles grids.

Grids give you the ability to define your column spacing by invisible (or visible) rectangular containers that are (usually) divisible by 12 columns.

[image: 12 column grid]

This allows for nesting as well which means you can have columns inside columns.

Assuming we're using a 12 column grid, nesting doesn't change anything in regard to the factor of 12. You always need 12 columns to make up 100% of the width.

Some good examples of grid libraries might be:

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com)

[Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/)